# TeamCity double backslash in path to ssdt

Tags: path, teamcity, sql-server-data-tools

I get the following error in my Teamcity build.

error MSB4062: The "SqlModelResolutionTask" task could not be loaded from the assembly `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\Dac\120\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Tasks.Sql.dll`.

Mind the `\\` between IDE and Extensions.
If I copy/paste the path on the build server and replace the double backslash by a single, I get the dll.

Any idea where this path is composed and how I can solve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The version you are using is a very old version - get the latest version of SSDT and test with that.

If you didn't want to do the whole download there is now a nuget package that will let you build the dacpac's which include this dll and the msbuild tasks, see:

See:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ssdt/2016/08/22/part-5-use-your-own-build-and-deployment-agent/

ed